# How to load different images inside very grid view in flutter?

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

```
import 'package:ecommerce_app/screens/home/item_details.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'catalog.dart';

class GridItems extends StatelessWidget {
  const GridItems({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: GridView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => ItemDetails(Item: items[index]),
                    ));
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0),
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      color: items[index].color,
                      boxShadow: const [
                        BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            blurRadius: 4,
                            spreadRadius: 2),
                      ]),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              items[index].detail,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'Anton',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            const Icon(
                              Icons.favorite,
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 247, 101, 90),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () {},
                          child: Image.asset(
                            items[index].image,
                            height: 100,
                            width: 100,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 8,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text(items[index].title,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'Anton',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                            const Text('\$100',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'SecularOne',
                                )),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:ecommerce_app/screens/home/grid/catalog.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_image_slideshow/flutter_image_slideshow.dart';

class ItemDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  const ItemDetails({
    super.key,
    required Item Item,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 226, 220, 220),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
              ),
            ),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: ImageSlideshow(
                      indicatorColor: Colors.red,
                      indicatorBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      indicatorRadius: 4,
                      isLoop: true,
                      height: 300,
                      autoPlayInterval: 3000,
                      children: [
                        Image.asset('assets/images/Sneakers1.png'),
                        Image.asset('assets/images/Sneakers2.png'),
                        Image.asset('assets/images/Sneakers4.png'),
                        Image.asset('assets/images/Sneakers7.png'),
                        Image.asset('assets/images/Sneakers9.png'),
                      ]),
                ),
                const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 20)),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, size: 25),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 8),
          const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20)),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: const [
              Text(
                'White Sneakers',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'LibreBaskerville',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Item {
  final String image, title, description, detail;
  final int id, price;
  final Color color;

  Item({
    required this.image,
    required this.detail,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.color,
    required this.id,
    required this.price,
  });
}

List<Item> items = [
  Item(
    title: "White Sneakers",
    image: "assets/images/Sneakers.png",
    description: 'dumytext',
    color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 190, 223, 245),
    detail: '20% off',
    id: 1,
    price: 100,
  ),
  Item(
    title: "Denim Jacket",
    image: "assets/images/Jackets.png",
    description: 'dumytext',
    color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 190, 223, 245),
    detail: '30% off',
    id: 2,
    price: 100,
  ),
  Item(
    title: "Chelsea Boots",
    image: "assets/images/Boots.png",
    description: 'dumytext',
    color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 190, 223, 245),
    detail: '30% off',
    id: 3,
    price: 150,
  ),
  Item(
      title: "Flannel Shirts",
      image: "assets/images/Shirts.png",
      description: 'dumytext',
      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 190, 223, 245),
      detail: '20% off',
      id: 4,
      price: 60),
];
```

This was my code. And I want to show different 4,5 images in every single grid view in flutter. Now I have added my code and everything. I just want to know that how to add every different image in different section of grid. like in "white sneakers" grid, I just want to add the images of white sneakers only.

Comment: Please add more information to your question.